# How do I download all e-mails from the server again with Outlook 2010?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

My existing Outlook 2010 PST file is corrupted and it cannot be repaired.

I don't delete my server e-mails (POP3) so all my 'old' e-mails are still on the server. How do I download them all again (there's about 3 years' worth (2GB 'ish of data going by the file size of my corrupted PST file)?

In the Outlook navigation space, a root folder containing about 20 sub-folders (all with old e-mails in) just disappeared today, so I can't access any of the old e-mails that were stored in the sub folders of the inbox.

But not all the inbox sub folders disappeared and for those that remain, I can still acess the old e-mails (which are presumably in the uncorrupted part of the corrupted .pst file).

How do I download all my old E-mails from the server? Do I have to make a new PST file for them to go into?

Answer (score 1):

### OPTION 1

If you have access to the server, you'd use the exchange management console to export a new pst.

If that's the case, follow this guide [here](http://exchangeserverpro.com/export-mailboxes-exchange-server-2010-sp1/), it's different from how it used to be done in 2007, but its essentially done from a PowerShell window.

or

### OPTION2

If you're a regular user and do not have access to the server, you'll need to build a new profile in outlook. Do that in the control panel.

From Control Panel, Select MAIL

[image: Add New Profile]

**Add New Profile**

[image: Name & Create]

**Name & Create**

[image: Set To Prompt]

**Set To Prompt**

Once you have a new profile, it should just redownload everything and you can build a new PST file from there.

Comment: I dont understand this apparently helpful answer.

Comment: do you have access to the server, yes or no? if no, build a new profile in the control panel.